# MySQL combine row results into a new column

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net, datagrid

I am trying to set up a query to return data to a VB.Net datagrid. I want to rollup the results into a new column kinda like below:

For example on Match-no:

```
Date     Sponsor    Match_no     Team
---------------------------------------
1-1-11     Nike        1         Tigers
1-1-11     Nike        1         Bears
2-1-11     Crisco      2         Llamas
2-1-11     Crisco      2         Tigers
```

Roll it up into a new column.

```
Date     Sponsor    Match_no     Teams_playing
---------------------------------------------------
1-1-11    Nike         1          Tigers vs Bears
2-1-11    Crisco       2          Llamas vs Tigers
```

I tried using "group_concat" but for some reason it rolled up the entire list on teams into a column regardless of match_no.

In this example there would be 4 tables :

```
Dates        Sponsors           Match          Team
------       --------         -------        --------
Date_id      Sponsor_id         Match_id       Team_id
Date         Sponsor_name       Match_no       Team_name
                                Sponsor_id     Match_id
```

Comment: You forgot to include the last portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  SELECT m.date,
         m.sponsor,
         m.match_no,
         GROUP_CONCAT(m.team, SEPARATOR ' vs ')
    FROM MATCH_NO m
GROUP BY m.date, m.sponsor, m.match_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure looks suspicious. Dates has no correspondence to Match. Team should be in a separate table with a bridge:

```
match_team
-----------
match_id
team_id
```

Or if there are only ever going to be two teams per match, then just

```
match
---------
match_id
Match_no
sponsor_id
date_id
team_id_a
team_id_b
```

Normally, one would not create a date table with just id and date, e.g. it doesn't help indexing or searching on the Match table by date.

For your original question, the query would be

```
select d.date, s.sponsor_name, m.match_no,
    group_concat(teams_playing separator ' vs ') Teams_playing
from match m
inner join dates d on d.date_id = m.date_id
inner join sponsors s on s.sponsor_id = m.sponsor_id
inner join team t on t.match_id = m.match_id
group by m.match_id, d.date, s.sponsor_name, m.match_no
```

Ref: [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks much! Sorry about the mess I didnt think it actally posted.

Comment: Did this work for you? You can click on the tick to accept it as an answer.